# Chrome Extension: Accessing string in storage for use in switch statement

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a short options page that's running and the value ('Yes' or 'No') gets passed to storage. Getting it out of storage and using it in a switch statement seems to be something of a production. I'd like to pass the value from storage to the variable `filterSetting` and use this string value to in my switch statement. I used an `alert();` to test whether or not anything was being passed into storage, so I know it's there.

Here's what I have in my content.js file. All permissions appear to be in place. Thoughts on where I've gone wrong would be appreciated.

```
var words = /minecraft|played/gi;

// obtain web page url for eventual identification
var url = window.location.href;

var filterSetting;

chrome.storage.sync.get('filter', function(data) { 
    filterSetting = data.filter;});

switch (filterSetting) {
    case "Yes":
        // generic filter
        alert("It worked!");
        break;
    case "No":
        // specific filter
```

Comment: shift your switch into the `function(data) { });` function

Comment: Hasn't quite done the job, but will continue to play with it. This is my first foray into chrome extensions JS/JQ. Many thanks for the reply!

Comment: FYI, callbacks in chrome API are invoked asynchronously.